# when main thread exits from thread join method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading java thread source code, there is a little problem I am not sure.
there are two thread, main thread and work thread which is a long time consumed thread, I want main thread to wait until work thread dies, so I call join method on work thread, in Thread source code, main thread waits when work thread is alive:

```
 while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
```

when work thread completes work and dies, so what happens to main thread now? does it notified by thread scheduler by calling notifyAll method on work thread automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the joining thread has called `wait()` as you've seen in the source code, then the target thread must call `notify()` or `notifyAll` to wake it up.

If you can't see that anywhere in the Thread source code, then it may happen in a different class, or the native code or the non-public JVM-vendor implementation code.

But that is an implementaion detail: you can be certain that `join` will return when the target thread finishes as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `workerThread.join()` from within the main thread will cause the main thread to pause execution until `workerThread` terminates.  Then, the main thread moves on to the next statement after the `join()` call.

This is demonstrated in the Java tutorial's [SimpleThreads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) example.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by main thread?
Are you implementing Runnable or are you making several Threads inside the class?
Could probably help you if you provided a little more code.